# Oracle data in 24 hour format

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a data in oracle that returns

```
select time from mytable
```

results

```
2/12/2015 8:58:30.000000 PM
```

How can I get the time to be in 24 format so it would read

```
2/12/2015 20:58:30.000000 PM
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have to convert it to a string to display it. Otherwise a simple SELECT date from table will convert the date into a string behind the scenes based on your default IDE settings or database settings.

The query to convert would be something like this -

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from mytable
```

HH24 is for 24 hour time. You can't have both 24 hour time and AM/PM in your time. So either `'HH24:MI:SS'` or `'HH:MI:SS AM'`.

If you want the fractional seconds and you have a datatype of TIMESTAMP, you can use FF for fractional seconds. So something like 'HH24:MI:SS:FF6'. The datatype DATE doesn't store fractional seconds.

More information about oracle [Date-time format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Comment: ruudvan - can i convert it back to a timestamp instead of a char. When I go to use it in my application it complains its not a data

Comment: It seems like the column was already a timestamp. So you wouldn't need to convert it to CHAR in the first place. You should only convert it to CHAR and format it in a certain way if you want to display the date in your front end application. If you don't want to display it in the front end, the format doesn't matter, as formatting is only applied while displaying. Basically to return it as a timestamp datatype, just return the value as is, and maybe let the app convert it to a format that is needed.